Konva: Using high cache while changing colors causes UI blocking
Due to my work requirements, I need to use high-resolution transformation images. However, I’ve noticed that the conversion process causes significant UI lag. Is there any way to overcome this issue?
clippedShape
  .cache({ pixelRatio: 50 })
  ?.filters([Konva.Filters.RGBA])
  .setAttrs({ red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1 });

